Copy data from multiple CSVs to worksheets of the same names in a master workbook
I'm trying to consolidate data from multiple csv files into a master workbook where each sheet matches up with each CSV file. The csvs are outputs from an analytics system. The names of the csvs will always be the same, they're all in the same folder as the master workbook and are updated asynchronously.
There is a PowerPoint presentation linked to the workbook and the aim is to quickly update all the charts in the presentation based on the latest csv outputs.
I.e. open a csv, copy everything there and paste it in the corresponding sheet of the same name overwriting what was there before.
The code is opening and closing the CSVs, as well as clearing what's already in each sheet but its not copying stuff over.
Sub ImportCSVs()
'Summary:   Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets
'           named for the CSV filenames

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
fPath = (Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\") 'path to CSV files, assumes local path of master workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv") 
On Error Resume Next
Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)                    'open a CSV file
    wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).UsedRange.Clear
    With wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fPath & fCSV, _
      Destination:=wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        Columns.AutoFit       
    End With  
    wbCSV.Close
    fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
MsgBox "Import is complete"
End Sub

Not throwing any error after removing On Error Resume Next.

First step, remove On Error Resume Next and see if any errors are being thrown.

@BigBen Not currently throwing up any errors when I do that!

An alternative approach would be to use Power Queries to refresh the CSV data

Why use a query table?  You can just copy the data from the opened CSV....

...you're not calling Refresh on your added query table.  Do you need to do all of this though?  Once you've added a querytable to each sheet (which you could do manually one time) you can just refresh them to pick up the latest data....
